# How are pyspark transformations wrapped in single method evaluated?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to organize couple data transformations, which are performed in pyspark. I have code similar to this below.

```python
def main():
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName(config.SPARK_CONFIG['AppName']) \
        .getOrCreate()
    data = getData(spark_session)

    analytics = Analytics(data)
    analytics.execute_and_save_analytics()

    spark_session.stop()


def getData(spark_session):    
    sqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(spark_session.sparkContext)
    return sqlContext.read.option('user', user).option('password', pswd)\
        .jdbc('jdbc:sqlserver://' + sqlserver + ':' + port\
        + ';database=' + database, table)


class Analytics():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def _execute(self):
        df0 = self.df.withColumn('col3', df.col31 + df.col32)
        # df0.persist()
        df1 = df0.filter(df.col3 > 10).groupBy('col1', 'col2').count()
        df2 = df0.filter(df.col3 < 10).groupBy('col1', 'col2').count()
        return df1, df2

    def execute_and_save_analytics(self):
        output_df1, output_df2 = self._execute()
        output_df1.coalesce(1).write.csv('/path/file.csv', header='true')
        output_df2.coalesce(1).write.csv('/path/file.csv', header='true')
```

How can I reorganize code in that way, that df0 will be evaluated only once? I tried to use persist() like in the commented line, but there wasn't any performance improvement. Any thoughts?

Another, yet similar problem, how would you organize your pipelines, if you had not one _execute(), but many similar methods _execute1(),  _execute2(), etc. 
I suppose if I call _execute() methods separately, then PySpark will evaluate each transformations pipeline separately (?), therefore I loose  performance.

edit: Given transformations (filter, groupBy, count) are only examples, I'm looking for solution working with any type of transformations or col3 definition.

edit2: It seems that calling cache() in init is the best optimization here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is (with `persist` commented out) `df0` will be evaluated twice anyway. The structure of you code won't have any impact at all.

Splitting your code into

```py
def _execute_1(self):
    df0 = self.df.withColumn('col3', df.col31 + df.col32)
    df1 = df0.filter(df.col3 > 10).groupBy('col1', 'col2').count()
    return df1

def _execute_2(self):
    df0 = self.df.withColumn('col3', df.col31 + df.col32)
    df2 = df0.filter(df.col3 < 10).groupBy('col1', 'col2').count()
    return df2
```

won't make any difference. Without going into details on `cache` guarantees you could:

```
def __init__(self, df):
    self.df = df.withColumn('col3', df.col31 + df.col32).cache()

def _execute_1(self):
    return df0.filter(df.col3 > 10).groupBy('col1', 'col2').count()

def _execute_2(self):
    return df0.filter(df.col3 < 10).groupBy('col1', 'col2').count()

def execute_and_save_analytics(self):
    output_df1 = self._execute_1()
    output_df2 = self._execute_2()
    output_df1.coalesce(1).write.csv('/path/file1.csv', header='true')
    output_df2.coalesce(1).write.csv('/path/file2.csv', header='true')
    self.df.unpersist()
```

but it could be easier to just:

```
(self.df
  .withColumn('col3', df.col31 + df.col32 > 10)
  .repartition("col3")
  .write.partitionBy("col3")
  .write.csv('/path/file.csv', header='true'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Starting from the end: Given transformations and col3 definition are only examples, I'm looking for a method which would work with any type of transformations and any number of different _execute() methods. I'll edit my question to clarify. 
I expect cache() (or persist()) within __init__ should do the job, I'll check it out. However I'd prefer to not cache anything until specific _execute() is called.

Comment: Tables are cached lazily. If you never execute an action, cache will never take place.

Comment: Great! didn't know that, I'll use it then:)